# Spring File Upload Etat HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to make an upload file form that uploads a file to a database and copy the file to a specified location but i always get this annoying error `Etat HTTP 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported` when i upload the file

*Here is my methods in the controller*

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/singleUploadimage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getSingleUploadPage(ModelMap model) {
        FileBucket fileModel = new FileBucket();
        Evennement e= new Evennement();
        model.addAttribute("fileBucket", fileModel);
        model.addAttribute("evennement", e);
        model.addAttribute("listequipe", this.equipeervice.findAll());
        return "testupload";    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/singleUploadimage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String singleFileUpload(@Valid FileBucket fileBucket,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute("evennement") Evennement p) throws IOException {


            System.out.println("Fetching file");
            MultipartFile multipartFile = fileBucket.getFile();

            // Now do something with file...
            FileCopyUtils.copy(fileBucket.getFile().getBytes(), new File( UPLOAD_LOCATION + fileBucket.getFile().getOriginalFilename()));
            String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            p.setImage(fileName);
            this.Evennementervice.addEvennement(p);

            model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);
            return "testupload";    
    }
```

*my form*

```
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="evennement"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <label for="file">Upload a file</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <form:input type="file" path="file" id="file" />
                            <div class="has-error">
                                <form:errors path="file" class="help-inline" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
    <div class="row">
                <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here the log error on tomcat

```
44846 [http-bio-8080-exec-520] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
 - Request method 'POST' not supported
44846 [http-bio-8080-exec-520] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Reque
st method 'POST' not supported
```

also i added the multipart resolver to web.xml

I don't get what i'm doing wrong ,any help is much appreciated .

Comment: Why does controller method include `@Valid FileBucket fileBucket`?

Comment: FileBucket is a class that contains the definition of the attribute **MultipartFile file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i solved this by adding in my form `action="/singleUploadimage?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"`